# Aggregate function $setField not updating in mongo database

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, pymongo

I wrote a code like below. The image of the product code in the database without running the code is as follows:

```
{
  "_id": "6364114b9b40fdf9721b4ddc",
  "urun": "AMD Ryzen 9 5900X 3.7GHz 64MB Önbellek 12 Çekirdek AM4 7nm İşlemci",
  "kategori": "islemci",
  "Fiyat": 3455
}
```

```
guncelFiyat = 2556
deneme = DenemeUrun.aggregate([{'$match':{'$text': { '$search': "AMD Ryzen 9 5900X 3.7GHz 64MB Önbellek 12 Çekirdek AM4 7nm İşlemci" }}},
                               {'$addFields':{'score':{'$meta':'textScore'}}}, 
                               {'$match':{'score':{'$gt': 2.2}}}, 
                               { "$sort": { 'score': -1 }}, 
                               {'$limit':1},
                               {'$replaceWith': 
                                 {'$setField':{
                                   'field': 'Fiyat',
                                   'input': '$$ROOT',
                                   'value':{'$switch':
                                              {'branches': [
                                                   {'case': { '$lte': 
                                                     [guncelFiyat,{'$multiply':[0.8, '$Fiyat']}]}, 'then': guncelFiyat}], 
                                                       'default': '$Fiyat'}}}}}
                              ])


doc = []
for doc in deneme:
    print(doc)
```

Jupyterlab output:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('6364114b9b40fdf9721b4ddc'), 
 'urun': 'AMD Ryzen 9 5900X 3.7GHz 64MB Önbellek 12 Çekirdek AM4 7nm İşlemci', 
 'kategori': 'islemci', 
 'Fiyat': 2556, 
 'score': 6.999999999999999}
```

But in mongoDB the 'Fiyat' does not change.

```
{
  "_id": "6364114b9b40fdf9721b4ddc",
  "urun": "AMD Ryzen 9 5900X 3.7GHz 64MB Önbellek 12 Çekirdek AM4 7nm İşlemci",
  "kategori": "islemci",
  "Fiyat": 3455
}
```

I want the 'Fiyat' line to change after checking. 'Fiyat' changes in Jupyterlab output but not in MongoDB.

$setField changes the jupyterLab output but not the field contained in mongoDb.
I want it to be in mongoDb as there is change in jupyterlab output.

Comment: Just a note, `aggregate` doesn't update documents. It is a processing pipeline so that you can query and transform the results into a format that you want. In this instance `$setField` is setting to OUTPUT of the query, not updating the stored data. If you wish to update, you should use the update, you can use the `updateMany` method. You CAN use some of the aggregation pipeline functions with this update method. Please see the docs here - https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/

Comment: Thank you so much! But I want to find and update document based on text score in one query. I can find the document with the aggregate function and update it with the updatemany function, but I will occupy the database 2 times. And I guess not all operators of aggregate function are used with updatemany :( @dangarfield

Comment: In this instance, it would potentially make sense to simply treat is a 2 stage process. 1) Get the data you require as you require (as per your current query) 2) After retrieving this in your application (and maybe adding a `'processed':true` attribute etc, do an update to that document with the new Fiyat and/or score. In many ways, if you're updating prices, it might be worth having an array with timestamps rather than a single field

Comment: too bad. It's right in front of us but we can't touch it. We have to implement different functions.

Comment: I'm talking about executing the second step inside the `for doc in deneme:` loop in the code you displayed. Maybe you could more clearly explain the constraints?